# ASIHTTPRequest sometimes doesn't receive header

Tags: iphone, ios, timeout, asihttprequest

I've never had this problem before but sometimes when I request data from my server (about 10% of the time) I never receive a response (not even the headers!) and the request times out. I use a networkQueue and it's set up like so

```
    //when initializing
    networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue queue] retain];
    networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;
    networkQueue.delegate = self;
    networkQueue.requestDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector = @selector(request:DidReceiveHeaders:);
    networkQueue.requestDidFinishSelector = @selector(NetworkQueueRouter:);
    networkQueue.requestDidFailSelector = @selector(requestDidFail:);
```

And I initialize the request with this method

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSURL *)url withParams:(NSDictionary *)params andUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.delegate = self;
    NSString *jsonString = [params yajl_JSONString];
    [request setPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"json"];
    request.timeOutSeconds = 30;
    if (info != nil)    request.userInfo = info;
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];
    [networkQueue go];
}
```

I only have this problem when using the iPhone or the iPhone Simulator. Sometimes while the request is taking forever, I'll check my browser with the same request and i'll get an immediate response from my browser while the iPhone is still requesting.

Has anyone experienced this before?